# How to connect terraform with AWS on a windows machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

How do I establish connectivity between terraform and my AWS account?
Do I need to install AWS CLI first?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the secret key and access key and paste it in the provider block in .tf file.
You can refer this tutorial
https://youtu.be/ODiSoZFxVRk

Answer (score 0):

Yes first you install the awscli then you install the terraform binary. Then write some terraform code and it will use the credentials stored in your AWS credentials when you installed the awscli.